# Laravel Detect Route Group in View

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel

In my admin pages, I want to manage my ecommerce products using AngularJS.

e.g. admin/product which will query an api in admin/api/product

I have not yet set up user authentication so I dont yet know if the user is an admin user or not.

I only wish to include angularjs admin scripts on admin pages.

Is there a way I can include an angular adminapp.js in my view only if the route group is admin. e.g. for public facing pages, I don't expose the adminapp.js to public facing pages.

I know I can do this if the user is authenticated as admin - but I wish to be able to do this if the route group is admin.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'namespace' => 'Admin'], function() {
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'api', 'namespace' => 'Api'], function() {
        Route::resource('product', 'ProductController');
    });

    Route::group(['namespace' => 'Product'], function() {
        Route::get('product', 'ProductController');
    });
});
```

And in the `templates.master.blade.php` something like:

```
@if($routeGroupIsAdmin)
    {{ HTML::script('js/adminapp.js') }}
@endif
```

or even:

```
{{ Route::getCurrentRoute()->getPrefix() == 'admin'? HTML::script('js/adminapp.js') : HTML::script('js/app.js') }}
```

But the problem with above example is that if I am in a deep nested view: admin/categories/products then my prefix will no longer be admin. I don't want to go down the route of using a regex to detect the word `admin` in the route prefix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no built in way that I know of, but here's something that works:

First, add a route filter

```
Route::filter('set-route-group', function($route, $request, $value){
    View::share('routeGroup', $value);
});
```

Then add this to your admin group (you can also use it for other groups in the future):

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'namespace' => 'Admin', 'before' => 'set-route-group:admin'], function(){
```

Also add this at the top of the `routes` file to make sure the `$routeGroup` variable is always set:

```
View::share('routeGroup', null);
```

Then in your view:

```
@if($routeGroup == 'admin')
    {{ HTML::script('js/adminapp.js') }}
@endif
```

Comment: Perfect - I have done this with a small variation:

Routes.php `'before' => 'admin'` filter applied
Filters.php `Route::filter('admin', function() {
 View::share('isGroupAdmin', true);
});`
templates.master.php `{{ isset($isGroupAdmin) ? HTML::script('js/adminapp.js') : HTML::script('js/app.js') }}` That way, when I build in the authentication component, I can just add the authentication logic to the this admin filter

Comment: Of course that works too. The advantage of the solution I proposed is that it is more generic and can be used with multiple route groups (I kept in mind that maybe a future visitor of this post could need that). One more thing, consider changing the name of your filter. Usually a before filter named only `admin` suggests that the filter somehow checks if the user has admin permissions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the route segments.

if your group prefix is 'admin' and the URL looks like this `http://example.com/admin/home`,
You can just check it on the blade using `Request::segment(1)`. it renders the first segment of the URL.

```
@if(Request::segment(1) == 'admin')
   {{HTML::script('js/adminapp.js')}}
@endif
```

If you are checking another segment just change the index.

Comment: Highly appreciated. Thanks Sahan

Comment: Can also do it like `request()->segment(1) == 'admin'`